# How do I use Sqlite in a dylib in an i386 app in XCode 4? This approach does work in iPhone app

Tags: xcode, sqlite, dylib, i386

Using Sqlite in a dylib in an i386 app in XCode 4

For iOS I needed to add a file namely libsqlite3.0.dylib from directory:
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/

I have a method that obtains and MaxID from a column of an sqlite DB.
This works fine in a universal iOS app I made. I want to port this code
over to a Mac app i386.

Because I could not find such an dylib for i386, I created one using
the download file: sqlite-autoconf-3070500.tar.gz

Following directions I produced 3 files in /usr/local/lib

libsqlite3.a
libsqlite3.la
libsqlite3.dylib

In XCode I have add '/usr/local/lib' to the 
 Build Setting->Search Paths->Library Search Paths

I have used:
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

I get the following build error when I uncomment the 
sqlite code in AppDelegate.m

Ld /Users/appleuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHungryMacNonDoc-dakfnxxiwzxehygtwrboebgysgwc/Build/Products/Debug/iHungryMacNonDoc.app/Contents/MacOS/iHungryMacNonDoc normal i386
    cd /Users/appleuser/Cocoa/iHungryMacNonDoc
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/appleuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHungryMacNonDoc-dakfnxxiwzxehygtwrboebgysgwc/Build/Products/Debug -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/appleuser/Cocoa/iHungryMacNonDoc/../SqliteLib -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/appleuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHungryMacNonDoc-dakfnxxiwzxehygtwrboebgysgwc/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/appleuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHungryMacNonDoc-dakfnxxiwzxehygtwrboebgysgwc/Build/Intermediates/iHungryMacNonDoc.build/Debug/iHungryMacNonDoc.build/Objects-normal/i386/iHungryMacNonDoc.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Cocoa -lsqlite3.0.8.6 -o /Users/appleuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHungryMacNonDoc-dakfnxxiwzxehygtwrboebgysgwc/Build/Products/Debug/iHungryMacNonDoc.app/Contents/MacOS/iHungryMacNonDoc

ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libdispatch_sim.dylib for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

AppDelegate.h begins
////////////

## import "AppDelegate.h"

## import "IngredXML.h"

## import "XmlListReader.h"

## import "Constants.h"

## import

## import

## import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"

Thanks so much for reading this. Please advise.
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd link against the SQLite dylib shipped in the SDK, which is at `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib` (substitute your target SDK as needed).

Comment: Thanks so much. I wish I had asked earlier!. My self compiled dylib

Comment: Thanks so much mipadi! You have the answer! I wish I had asked earlier!. My self-compiled dylib worked but only after I read the following in a post and removed the library search paths (pointing to iPhone version)from the XCode project:::: Make sure you don't have any custom search paths defined which misdirect the linker to look in odd places for the library. – Claus Broch Jun 10 '10 at 12:33